# How can I draw a bunch of squares?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am very new to python. I need to draw this shape for college but i find it really hard so i am trying to do square before going into that image.

Anyway here is my question: How can i have 8 rows? (There are 8 square in 1 row) I can not keep adding `def start_point1():` This wouldn't be the proper way to do it.

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import turtle as t
import time

def start_point():
    t.penup()
    t.setpos(-200,-240)
    t.pendown()

def start_point1():
    t.penup()
    t.setpos(-200,-180)
    t.pendown()

def draw_turtle():
    for a in range(4):
        t.forward(60)
        t.left(90)

def draw_turtlerow():
    for a in range(8):
        draw_turtle()
        t.forward(60)



def main():
    start_point()
    draw_turtlerow()
    start_point1()
    draw_turtlerow()
```

Comment: How about a loop? You can compute your start/end coordinates and pass them as arguments to your drawing functions inside a loop. A loop would go over as many elements as you need.

Comment: ask yourself, what does this draw? how is it different from what I expected?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this kind of problems, you should ask yourself what is the "atomic" operation that - repeated over and over - will generate your complete solution. You already found your basic "atom": drawing a side of a square:

```
t.forward(60)
```

Now, what is the next level of "atomicity"? Well, repeating four times a side, you can get a square (as you correctly found out yourself)

```
for a in range(4):
    t.forward(60)
    t.left(90)
```

Now along the same lines, you might come to the conclusion that if you repeat 8 times the above, you get a line, and if you repeat 8 times a line you'll get a complete check board. It should be something like:

```
for col in range(8):
    for row in range(8):
        # draw a square here
```

Now, you already wrote yourself the function to draw a square, the only problem is that you would need to draw each of them at different locations. The key point you have to focus here is: **can you think of a method to calculate this location starting from the values of `col` and `row`?**

If you get stuck, I posted a sample implementation [here](http://pastebin.com/KmCfHA2K), **I'm confident you won't need to check that out**, but if you do, here's the extra assignment: instead of using that code as-is, turn the inner circle in a call to a separate function `draw_square(row, col)`.

**EDIT:** For extra points and pride, once completed the exercise, **observe how most lines in the check board are redrawn over and over**. With very little effort you can double the efficiency of your program. Can you think how?

HTH!

Comment: thanks alot. i managed to get the squares working but i can not figure it out how to draw that shape. i am still working on it :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding arguments to `start_point` instead of creating new versions of 
the function. For instance:

```
def start_point(x,y):
    t.penup()
    t.setpos(x,y)
    t.pendown()
```

With this, you can eliminate `start_pos1()` and you are reusing code, which is good.

Along these lines, consider adding some flexibility to your other functions as well. For instance, why not have `draw_turtlerow` take a number that tells it how many squares to draw in the row? Then you could make another method that takes the number of rows you want - this function would then call `draw_turtlerow` and `start_pos` several times to draw the entire grid.

I'm not sure this is the right direction for you assignment, but I hope it points you in the right direction.